# carga de datos de un JSON en un onload() no muestra los datos

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Estoy intentando mostrar en mi index.html los contenidos de un archivo JSON que he creado. Para ello estoy utilizando el onload() en el body a una función que se encuentra en el script.js. He acabado el método y no aparece la información, y amarece un error en la consola que dice:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload (script.js:14)"

El fallo aparece si dejo la línea que pone "ourRequest.send()". Si comento esta linea, el error no se mostrará, pero tampoco se muestra la información

Este es el index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Showing comments stored in json</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body onload="commentLoad()">

    <article>
        <div class="container"></div>
    </article>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Este es el script.js

```
function commentLoad(){
    

    var textContainer = document.getElementById("container");
    

    var ourRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    ourRequest.open('GET','comments.json');
    ourRequest.onload = function(){
        var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        var userCommentData = "";
        
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            userCommentData += "<p> User Name: " + ourData[i].name + " Score: " + ourData[i].score + " <p> User Comment: " + ourData[i].comment + "</p> </p>"; 
        }
        textContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',userCommentData);
        
       
    }
    ourRequest.send();
 
}
```

Y para terminar, este es el comments.json

```
[{
        "name": "John",
        "score": "5",
        "comment": "Best thing I have ever tried"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "Tom",
        "nota": "4",
        "comentario": "Very good"
    }

]
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes! El idioma oficial del sitio es el español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas tooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!!), por favor.

Comment: Perdona! Ya he hecho la traducción al español. Un saludo.